# How to assign an incremented value to Insert-ed, Updated-ed row

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a table named Users and I have an editVersion column in it.

```
+----+------+-------------+
| id | name | editVersion |
+----+------+-------------+
|  1 | John |           1 |
+----+------+-------------+
```

After a new User is added, I want to assign them the highest editVersion like

```
+----+------+-------------+
| id | name | editVersion |
+----+------+-------------+
|  1 | John |           1 |
|  2 | Jane |           2 |
+----+------+-------------+
```

And after each edit is made to any user, I want to assign them the highest editVersions in the editVersion column. Like if John's name is changed to John Doe, his editVersion would change to

```
+----+----------+-------------+
| id | name     | editVersion |
+----+----------+-------------+
|  1 | John Doe |           3 |
|  2 | Jane     |           2 |
+----+----------+-------------+
```

My question is how can I do this by without having to query the table for Max(editVersion). Can I use Triggers for this? If so, how?

Or can I write an sql Update, where while setting the fields, I can also get the Max(editVersion), increment it and assign to editVersion?

Comment: its not easy but this maybe help u: [emulating-nextval-function-to-get-sequence-in-mysql](http://www.microshell.com/database/mysql/emulating-nextval-function-to-get-sequence-in-mysql/)

Comment: Can the first row be deleted? What effect would this have on the editversion? And why not simply store a timestamp?

Comment: @Strawberry I am afraid the previous can not be deleted since its 'id' field is tied elsewhere and is auto_increment.

Comment: No need to be afraid! I'm just asking if the design allows for it or not. Incidentally, AUTO_INCREMENT has no implications for row deletion - that's rather the point of it! Anyway, so yes - a timestamp is definitely the way to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is the aim of such function. But this may fail if such `editVersion` field is updated explicitly.

**Suggestions**:

1. Write `BEFORE` timed `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers on the table.
2. Select `MAX( editVersion ) + 1` in to a local variable.
3. Set the local variable value into `NEW.editVersion`.

Comment: This is the code that I have written, but it gives an error
CREATE TRIGGER changeEditVersion
BEFORE INSERT
ON USER
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE x;
SET x = (SELECT MAX(editVersion) from Users)+1;
NEW.editVersion = x;
END;

Comment: It should be `declare x int;` Data type of `'x'` was missing.

Comment: select can also be: `select max( editVersion ) + 1 into x from users;`